# Using the @MinDate from class-validator results in TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTime' of undefined?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, typescript2.0, class-validator

I have a class like this:

```
    export default class Order {
      sku: string;
      @IsDate()
      purchaseDate: Date;
      @IsDate()
      @MinDate(this.purchaseDate)
      receiptDate: Date;
    }
```

I create an order instance like this:

```
    const o = new Order();
    o.sku = "sku1";
    o.purchaseDate = new Date(2014, 11, 17);
    o.receiptDate = new Date(2016, 11, 17);
```

And validate:

```
    validate(o).then((errors:ValidationError[]) => { // errors is an array of validation errors
        if (errors.length > 0) {
            console.log("validation failed. errors: ", errors);
        } else {
            console.log("validation succeed");
        }
    });
```

Which results in the following error:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTime' of undefined
  at Validator.minDate (src/validation/Validator.ts:414:49)
```

The full test code looks like this:

```
    import { validate, ValidationError } from "class-validator";

    import 'mocha';

    describe('Order Validation', () => {
        it('should be a valid order', () => {
            const o = new Order();
            o.sku = "sku1";
            o.purchaseDate = new Date(2014, 11, 17);
            o.receiptDate = new Date(2016, 11, 17);

            validate(o).then((errors:ValidationError[]) => { // errors is an array of validation errors
                if (errors.length > 0) {
                    console.log("validation failed. errors: ", errors);
                } else {
                    console.log("validation succeed");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to pass Typescript decorator object values in at runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43742615/is-it-possible-to-pass-typescript-decorator-object-values-in-at-runtime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I asked the question differently here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43742615/is-it-possible-to-pass-typescript-decorator-object-values-in-at-runtime).  Decorators support only compile time values.  Values available at runtime cannot be passed in, hence the issue I'm having in the above scenario.